# How to pass model value IFormFile from view to controller On Change event

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor

```js
$(".uploadFile").on('change', function () {
        console.log('new file uploaded')
        //var array = $("#productImage").getIdArray();
        var file_data =$(this).find(".productImage").prop("files")[0];
        var files = event.target.files
        $(this).find(".imageViewer").attr("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]));
        var form_data = new FormData();
        var product_Id = (this.ProductId) ;
        var viewModel = { ProductId: product_Id, ProductImage: file_data};
        form_data.append("file", file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DailyMenuPlanner/AddPhoto",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: viewModel,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success == true) { alert("success!"); }
                else { alert("fail!"); }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="col">
    
                            <ul class="list-group mt-3">
                                @if (Model.Products != null && Model.Products.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <input asp-for="@Model.Products[i].IsChecked" type="checkbox" />
                                            <label asp-for="@Model.Products[i].ProductId">  @Model.Products[i].ProductName</label>
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Products[i].ProductId"/>
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Products[i].ProductName" asp-route-productId/>
                                            <div  class="uploadFile float-end">
                                                <label class="file-label">
                                                    <img class="imageViewer" width="50" height="50" style="border: 1px solid #000000; cursor:pointer;" />
                                                </label>
                                                <input asp-for="@Model.Products[i].ProductImage" asp-for-ProductId="@Model.Products[i].ProductId" type="file" class="productImage" onchange="getImage(this.value);" style="visibility:none; display:none"/>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <li class="list-group-item">nodata</li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

```
[.js]
$(".uploadFile").on('change', function () {
        console.log('new file uploaded')
        //var array = $("#productImage").getIdArray();
        var file_data =$(this).find(".productImage").prop("files")[0];
        var files = event.target.files
        $(this).find(".imageViewer").attr("src", window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]));
        var form_data = new FormData();
        var product_Id = (this.ProductId) ;
        var viewModel = { ProductId: product_Id, ProductImage: file_data};
        form_data.append("file", file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DailyMenuPlanner/AddPhoto",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: viewModel,
            type: 'post',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success == true) { alert("success!"); }
                else { alert("fail!"); }
            }
        });
    });

[controller method]
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> AddPhoto(DailySelectedProductViewModel dataModel)
        {
            IFormFile file = dataModel.ProductImage;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                byte[] imageAsArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            return Json(file.FileName);
            
        }
```

Here, I am getting null value in my ViewModel from view, I have of one list of elements and each elements have choose file (innput type="file") with them. on choosing any image On Change event get trigger and then it calls the controller method but i am getting stuck that how can i send the model value from view to controller. also the productImage is of datatype = IFormFile. so after getting it pass from view to controller how can i convert it into bytes or does sqlserver column with "image" type save it directly ?

please help me with this issue!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **data:form-data,** and you can  insert key with values into this **FormData()** obj  then you can transmit it to your controller. If you want to know more about **FormData()** then read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Below is a work demo,you can refer to it:

controller.cs:

```
 public class AAController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> uploader(UploadVm model)
        {
            return this.View();
        }     
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="upload-button">        
      <input id="id"   type="text" />
       <input id="type" type="text" />
      <input id="files" name="files" type="file" size="1" multiple onchange="uploadFiles('files');" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
      
function uploadFiles(inputId) {
  var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
  var files = input.files;
  var formData = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
    formData.append("files", files[i]);
  }
   //Add the input element values
    formData.append("Type", $("#type").val());
   formData.append("Id", $("#id").val());
  $.ajax(
    {
      url: "/AA/uploader",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: "POST",
      success: function (data) {
        alert("Files Uploaded!");
      }
    }
  );
}
    </script>  
}
```

Uploader.cs:

```
public class UploadVm
    {
        public string Type { set; get; }
        public string Id { set; get; }
        public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```